# How does "attachments" option in exextra work?

Tags: moodle, r-exams

I would like to know more about the `attachments` option in `\exextra`. Does this option allow the attachment(s) from students when they are submitting their answers? I could not find any worked example on this feature in http://www.r-exams.org/ or in any other sources. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We haven't advertised this option much because we hope to further improve and streamline it in the future. There is one worked example, though: http://www.R-exams.org/templates/essayreg/. Essentially all the `exextra` options specified in that exercise map to the corresponding options in Moodle.

Comment: Thanks so much! That's cool. As I see the worked file, the attachment option allows the students to attach their files. In addition to this, would it also be possible for lecturers to attach their files with correct solutions & answers which will be available to students after they submit their work on Moodle?

Comment: The `solution` section/environment can contain everything that the `question` section/environment contains and it is shown to the participants after they have entered their answer. So you can either write the solution directly but also embed a file that the participants can download.